# Silverlight browser compabibility script

Tags: javascript, silverlight, browser, plugins

Now that we have a couple of web browser not supporting Silverlight, I would like to create a better experience for my users, informing about this compatibility issue and guiding them to use Firefox, IE or Safari(maybe).

The current Silverlight plugin detect script leads to bad user experience, since it keeps prompting user to install the plugin, even if it is already installed. In my opinion, it should inform about the incompatibility, if it is the case.

Microsoft Edge has a great feature that detectes some incompatibility sites and shows a great message orienting to proceed with IE instead. But this does not apply to my website. You can have a look on the message in this article:

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/edge-displays-this-website-needs-internet-explorer-message

How can we make a mix of both features and solve this problem?

Thank you,

Igor.